# Taking user input 'n' times PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to write a PL/SQL program that takes user input 'n' times. Here n is 10, but this only takes input 1 time and displays that input value 10 times as the loop is from 1 to 10. How can I write a program that takes 'n' input values and display them.

```
set serveroutput on;
DECALRE
num NUMBER(10);
BEGIN

for i in 1..10 
loop
    dbms_output.put_line(&num);
    END loop;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set serveroutput on;
DECALRE
num NUMBER(10) := &num;

BEGIN

for i in 1..10 
loop
    dbms_output.put_line(num);
    END loop;
END;
/
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand but this part makes me think I'm correct "Here n is 10, but this only takes input 1 time and displays that input value 10 times as the loop is from 1 to 10."

Answer (score 0):

PL/SQL is not an interactive language. It is SQL*Plus that is prompting you for a value and it needs to get all the substitution values it needs before it can send the PL/SQL block to the database to be executed.

So, there is no way for PL/SQL to prompt the user for input in loop.

Comment: task given to me was :- "insert 10 records into a table using loop - pl/sql"

Comment: so if there were 5 columns in a table, do i have to use 50 variables for insertion ?

Comment: @DaniyalJavaid as I mentioned it is not possible to use interactive action. But, there are several way, you can use loop counter or could use other table

Answer (score 0):

Reading through the comments:

> task given to me was :- "insert 10 records into a table using loop -
>   pl/sql"

and

> so if there were 5 columns in a table, do i have to use 50 variables
>   for insertion ?

Answer to your above question is **NO** if you want the `same set of records` to be inserted to your table 10 times. Below is the way you can do it. When you execute the block, it will ask you to promt value for 5 columns and accordingly it would insert 10 set of records with the same value to the table. See below.

```
SQL> DECLARE
       num1   NUMBER (10) := &num1;
       num2   NUMBER (10) := &num2;
       num3   NUMBER (10) := &num3;
       num4   NUMBER (10) := &num4;
       num5   NUMBER (10) := &num5;
    BEGIN
       FOR i IN 1 .. 10
          LOOP
          INSERT INTO TAB (col1,
                           col2,
                           col3,
                           col4,
                           col5)
               VALUES (num1,
                       num2,
                       num3,
                       num4,
                       num5);
       END LOOP;
       COMMIT;
    END;
    /   
    Enter value for num1: 1
    old   2:    num1   NUMBER (10) := &num1;
    new   2:    num1   NUMBER (10) := 1;
    Enter value for num2: 2
    old   3:    num2   NUMBER (10) := &num2;
    new   3:    num2   NUMBER (10) := 2;
    Enter value for num3: 3
    old   4:    num3   NUMBER (10) := &num3;
    new   4:    num3   NUMBER (10) := 3;
    Enter value for num4: 4
    old   5:    num4   NUMBER (10) := &num4;
    new   5:    num4   NUMBER (10) := 4;
    Enter value for num5: 5
    old   6:    num5   NUMBER (10) := &num5;
    new   6:    num5   NUMBER (10) := 5;

    PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

OUTPUT:

```
SQL> select * from tab;    

      COL1       COL2       COL3       COL4       COL5
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2          3          4          5
         1          2          3          4          5
         1          2          3          4          5
         1          2          3          4          5
         1          2          3          4          5
         1          2          3          4          5
         1          2          3          4          5
         1          2          3          4          5
         1          2          3          4          5
         1          2          3          4          5

10 rows selected.
```